# How can I increase the kernel frequency to 1000Hz?

Tags: kernel

I'm currently running Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS

My kernel runs at 250Hz, as can be seen by the output of:

```
grep 'CONFIG_HZ=' /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

How can I make it 1000Hz? All posts I've found are old/outdated.

I understand that I need to recompile the kernel, however the instructions I've found don't work with my version

Comment: 6,8 has it https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/noble/commit/?h=master-next&id=2396118b8bc59c35fb50839e8f190922251c3fad  configured.  anyone interested in this here is a good read https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/enable-low-latency-features-in-the-generic-ubuntu-kernel-for-24-04/42255/5

Comment: Thank you, if I've seen correctly - it will be available in version 24.04 that will be released in April? But from the article I couldn't see how to enable/disable low latency, is it just changing config file values? Without the need to recompile the kernel?

Comment: No idea on that :D there are hints on a setup in userspace where you can create a profile. But if that will make 24.04 no idea :D just a few more weeks ;)

Comment: Kernel 6.8 in 24.04 will be 1000 Hz by default and there will no longer be any such thing as a "low latency" kernel. The generic kernel will be 1000Hz.

Comment: @DougSmythies, thank you. Do you know how this might work on a cloud server like an EC2 instance on AWS? Some said that it won't matter because AWS is managed and something about the hypervisor not modifiable so it won't matter much?

Comment: Did I see the same question over on ubuntu forums? I do not know the answer. I use full virtualisation, so can use whatever kernel I want in the virtual machines. Others might use VM methods that depend on the host kernel.